# Find and get (multiple) object value(s) from two different arrays

Tags: javascript

Is there a solution to check in JavaScript if two objects have the same value and then get the value?

Here is some code for demonstration:

An Object in Array 1 (“generalData”):

```
const generalData = [{
“specificId”: 210001,
“name”:  "Test 1",
“optionsAvaiable”: false,
“mode”: 0
}, …]
```

An Object in Array 2 (“selectedData”):

```
const selectedData = [{
“specificId”: 210001,
“name”: "Test 1"
“optionsAvaiable”: false,
“column”: {“disableHtmlEncode”: true, “allowSorting”: false, “allowResizing”: true, “allowFiltering”: false, ”allowGrouping”: false, …},
“foreignKeyData”: undefined,
“index”: "0",
“mode”: 0
}, …]
```

I want to get the specific id so the expected output is `210001` or (if there are multiple matches) `[210001, 210003, 210009]`

My current solution (messy):

```
this.generalData.forEach(generalDataObj => {
  this.selectedData.forEach(selectedDataObj => {
    if (generalDataObj.specificId == selectedDataObj.specificId) {
        console.log(generalDataObj.specificId); // (210001)
      };
   });
});
```

Is there a cleaner solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the `specificId` field, and calculate the intersection between the two arrays like this:

```js
const generalData = [
  {
    specificId: 210001,
    name: "Test 1",
    optionsAvaiable: false,
    mode: 0,
  },
];

const selectedData = [
  {
    specificId: 210001,
    name: "Test 1",
    optionsAvaiable: false,
    column: {
      disableHtmlEncode: true,
      allowSorting: false,
      allowResizing: true,
      allowFiltering: false,
      allowGrouping: false,
    },
    foreignKeyData: undefined,
    index: "0",
    mode: 0,
  },
];

const extractProperty = (prop) => (x) => x[prop];

const extractSpecificId = extractProperty("specificId");

const intersect = generalData
  .map(extractSpecificId)
  .filter((x) => selectedData.map(extractSpecificId).includes(x));

console.log(intersect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, using a [Set](https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html).

```js
// A set containing the specificIds of all selected items
let selectedDataIds = new Set(this.selectedData.map(item => item.specificId));

// returns an array of specificIds in both selectedData and generalData
const intersectionIds = this.generalData.filter(item => selectedDataIds.has(item.specificId));

console.log(intersectionIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) over them, and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over each one building an output array.

```js
const generalData = [{specificId: 210001},{specificId: 211001},{userId: 215001}];
const selectedData = [{userId: 310001},{specificId: 411001},{personId: 215301}];

const out = [generalData, selectedData].flatMap(arr => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
    if (c.specificId) acc.push(c.specificId);
    return acc;
  }, []);
});

console.log(out);
```